# How to do "page transitions" in Ratchet without AJAX

Tags: ratchet-bootstrap

I like the visual effect of page transitions in Ratchet but I want to build my entire app as a single HTML app.

I'd like to be able to switch pages without AJAX. Is that possible?

If it was jQuery (or Angular) I'd do something like this

```
<html>
<header class="bar bar-nav">
  <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</header>
<div class="content" id="page1">
   <a href="#" onclick="$('#page1').hide();$('#page2').show()">Page 2</a>
</div>
<div class="content" id="page2">
   <a href="#" onclick="$('#page2').hide();$('#page1').show()">Page 1</a>
</div>
</html>
```